# Are Graph Neural Networks (GNNs) generalizations of Convolutional Neural Networks (CNNs)?

Tags: conv-neural-network, graph-neural-network

In lecture 4 of [this course](https://gnn.seas.upenn.edu/), the instructor argues that GNNs are generalizations of CNNs, and that one can recover CNNs from GNNs. He presents the following diagram (on the right) and mentions that it represents both a CNN and a GNN. In particular, he mentions that if we particularize the graph shift operator (i.e the matrix S, which in the case of a GNN could represent the adjacency matrix or the Laplacian) to represent a directed line graph, then we obtain a time convolutional filter (which I hadn’t heard of before watching this, but now I know that all it does is shift the graph signal in the direction of the arrows at each time step). That part I understand. What I don’t understand is how we can obtain 2D CNNs (the ones that we would for example apply to images) from GNNs. I was wondering if someone could explain.
[image]

Comment: Could you expand the acronym for clarity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on many things, but I think generally no, they are not equivalent.

By design, GNNs almost always act identically on isomorphic graphs. It would be pretty strange if this wasn't the case, seeing as the point of GNNs are to exploit graph symmetries.

By contract, CNNs do not act identically on flipped or rotated images. CNN filters have a notion of up, down, right, left, etc.

Therefore in the most straightforward sense, they're not equivalent. Of course you can augment graphs with a notion of neighbor ordering, and maybe design a GNN which takes advantage of this, but that's not the standard use case of GNNs.

Here's a quote from one of the foundational works in the area ([fast localized spectral filtering](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.09375.pdf)):

> The gap in performance may be explained
> by the isotropic nature of the spectral filters, i.e. the fact that edges in a general graph do not
> possess an orientation (like up, down, right and left for pixels on a 2D grid).